# Should getSystemService(...) result be cached?

Tags: android

The documentation of [`getSystemService`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSystemService%28java.lang.String%29) advises to **not share the service objects between various different contexts**.

For a single context, is it preferable to cache the service object by assigning it to a instance field in `onCreate()` or it should be obtained at the time of use? What is the idiomatic usage?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since holding a system service object has very little ongoing cost, I recommend holding onto it in a data member. Whether you get one in `onCreate()` or lazy-initialize it if/when needed is up to you.

Note that *using* a system service object may have significant costs. Holding a `LocationManager` instance is cheap; using GPS (e.g., via `requestLocationUpdates()`) is not cheap.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer that some service object are more costly then others.

Comment: Why do you recommend storing the service? Do you think there's much cost to calling `getSystemService`?

Comment: @Sam: "Do you think there's much cost to calling getSystemService?" -- it's probably not huge, but it might involve IPC.

Answer (score 0):

I was about to ask the same. Here's how I do it - inside a service (which inherits from Context)

```
private static volatile LocationManager lm; // not final - we need a context

private LocationManager lm() {
    LocationManager result = lm;
    if (result == null) {
        synchronized (LocationMonitor.class) { // my service
            result = lm;
            if (result == null)
                result = lm = (LocationManager)
                    getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```